# With infinite observations, would the weights resulting from ridge regression be the same as simple linear regression?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, linear-regression, weighted-data, ridge-regression

As the number of observations approaches infinity, do the weights of a linear regression approach the weights of a linear regression with L2 penalty?